# Efficiently wrapping a double

Tags: swift, swift3, double

I have a number of geometric functions that only accept angles in the range 0° to 360°.  If the angle is outside that range then the angle is invalid (i.e. converting 365° to 5° is not an option) and there's no point in calling the functions.  To this end I've created the following class:

```
struct PositiveAngle {
    public let value: Double

    init?(value: Double) {
        guard 0.0 <= value && value <= 360.0 else {
            return nil
        }
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

To be used as follows:

```
let angle = PositiveAngle(value: 30.0)
print(angle.value)

func foo(angle: PositiveAngle) -> PositiveAngle {
    ...
}
```

This works but it feels "clunky" because I have extract the value of the angle from the struct whenever I need to use it.  Given that all I am after is a `Double` that has a restricted range, is there a more efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Why is wrap-around / modulus (e.g. 365º -> 5º) not an option?

Comment: If you needed that option then it could be incorporated into the guard statement in the initialiser.  However, for the purposes of my calculations anything outside the started range is not a valid angle.  In any case, that is a separate question.  This question is about how best to restrict the range of a double (and preferable still behave like a Double rather than a class that contains a Double).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to access `.value` in every function, you will have to add helper functions by yourself.

For example, to define `sin`:

```
func sin(_ angle: PositiveAngle) -> Double {
    return sin(angle.value * Double.pi / 180)
}
```

Now you will be able to call `sin` with your `PositiveAngle` as an argument directly.

You can do the same for operators, e.g. `+`, `-` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a struct with a static function

```
struct AngleChecker {
    static func validate(_ value : Double) -> Double? {
       return (0.0...360.0).contains(value) ? value : nil
    }
}

let x = AngleChecker.validate(12.0) // --> 12.0
let y = AngleChecker.validate(362.0) // --> nil
```

Comment: That would certainly do the validation but the main aim is to ensure functions cannot be called with invalid parameters hence "func foo(angle: PositiveAngle) -> PositiveAngle".  The thing I don't want to do is to accept a Double and than have to validate it within each of the methods and also to guarantee that the returned value is a valid value.

Comment: As far as I know you can't do that. An alternative is to insert `assert` lines e.g. `assert((0.0...360.0).contains(value), "angle out of range")`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do modulus, for reasons that aren't entirely clear to me, but I have done a lot of angle maths over the years and have always used wrap-around. In Swift,

```
extension Double {
    var positiveAngleInDegrees: Double {
        var x = self
        while x < 0 { x += 360 }
        while x >= 360 { x -= 360 }
        return x
    }
}

let y = 722.positiveAngleInDegrees // 2
```

In mathematical terms 722º is entirely equivalent to 2º.

Comment: I don't want to do modulus because the angle is in reference to a rotor which must not rotate more than one turn.  Any request to turn it to a position outside the permissible range is invalid as is any function's result outside the permitted range.  (Precondition: The rotor is at a valid angle;  Postcondition: The rotor will at a valid angle.)  Thus even if there is an error within the function, the hardware will not attempt to turn the rotor to a position that cannot be reached.